# Swiftmailer: failing to authenticate from the server

Tags: php, symfony, email, gmail, swiftmailer

### My issue

I can't configure my website to send emails.

On my localhost, using the same config file and the same email parameters, emails are being sent just fine. However, my website fires error 500 when I try to send an email:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username 'xxx@xxx.xxx' 
using 1 possible authenticators
```

So it is able to authenticate on my local server, but not online.

It used to work properly prior to my last update and no changes have been made to the configuration files since then.

### What I have tried so far

- I have tried all the possible configs I could find on related subjects (with "~" or filling the info by myself "ssl", "login")
- I have also tried various gmail address in order to see if it was account related or not. One giving access to "less secure apps" and the other not giving it access, which should not matter anyway since I did not configure the 2-steps verification.
- I have cleared the cache, with the command line and manually, many times.
- Finally, I have double checked my server DNS settings and everything seems to be in order.

Honnestly, I am at a loss right now and don't know what to try.

### Files content

Just in case, here are my `config.yml` file:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
    host:       "%mailer_host%"
    encryption: ssl
    port:       465
    username:   "%mailer_user%"
    password:   "%mailer_password%"
    auth_mode:  login
    #spool:      { type: memory }
```

and `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    [...]
    mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: ~
    mailer_user: xxx@xxx.xxx
    mailer_password: thisContainsThePassword
```

Comment: I've been having problems sending from gmail from my application as well. I ended up using Sendgrid for my transaction emails and added Gmail MX records for business emails. Haven't had a problem since.

Comment: I did just that (installing SendGrid on my symfony app) and it gives me the same error, which makes me think it is not related to gmail at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this configuration :

```
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Tried it, will try again.